# I can't read the _id property of a JSON object stored in MongoDB (MongoLab service)

Tags: json, mongodb, heroku, objectid

I have a document on a mongodb on Heroku. Each object in the document has a system generated object id in the form of

```
"_id": {
        "$oid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
```

When I make a query and get the response from the server, I stringify the response using JSON.stringify and I log the object on the server console. When I do this the following gets logged:

```
this is the response: [{"creator":"al","what[place]":"home","what[time [start]":"22:00","what[time][end]":"","what[details]":"","who[]":["joe","kay","mau"],"_id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}]
```

Right after the full object gets logged, I try to log the id to make sure I can access it... I want to then pass the id to a different object so that I can have a reference to the logged object.

I have this right now:

```
var stringyfied = JSON.stringify(res);
console.log("this is the response: " + stringyfied);
console.log("id: " + stringyfied._id);
```

but when the item is logged I get

```
id: undefined
```

instead of

```
id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

No matter how I try to access the _id property, I keep getting undefined even though it get printed with the console.log for the full object

I've tried:

```
stringyfied.id
stringyfied["_id"]
stringyfied["id"]
stringyfied._id.$oid
stringyfied.$oid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being returned is an array with one object in it.

The way to access the `_id` is with `stringyfied[0]._id`. However, it would be cleaner to pull the object out of the array instead.

There are a few ways you can do that. If this query will only ever return one result and that's all you'll want, you can use the [findOne method](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) instead. If the query may return more than a single document, then you will want to [loop through the returned results](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#with-foreach-method).

I also agree with @dariogriffo that you'll need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the stringified JSON variable.

Comment: thanks! that makes sense. I now have:
   
   console.log("this is the response: " + JSON.stringify(res));
   console.log("id: " + res[0]._id);

this works, there were two issues, first I was trying to access the string as if it was an object. The server's response was an object in an array on the first place so I didn't need to convert it to a string but rather access the first element of the array. the other problem is that I was accessing the array as if it was a JSON object instead of pulling the object out of the array as you suggested. The problem is now fixed. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

you need to use JSON.parse(), cause JSON.stringify() is to convert to string, parse is to get the object. stringifiedid is a string

Comment: thank you @dariogriffo, you were right. I actually didn't even need to convert the object to a string on the first place it is already an object in an array when the server returns it as a response. I was unnecessarily making it a string as soon as I got it back.